# How to rename, remove, or add data elements to a set of values React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I am developing a dropdown of departments for use in a location edit form, and I would like to know if there is a way to rename an element of create a new one in my set of values.

The API used to populate my table is only sending these data elements, not the full record which does include a departmentId column:

```
    "id": 1 
    "name": "23456",
    "description": "New Location",
    "departmentName": "Tools"
```

My department dropdown is being populated using another API which supplies me these elements:

```
    "name": "Tools",
    "id": "1",
```

The problem is, the API I have been given for posting back to the database is expecting a department ID, not department name, and is looking for this data structure:

```
     "id": 1 
     "name": "23456",
     "description": "New Location",
     "departmentOther": {
         "id": 1
     }
```

How can I manipulate the values I am given to be able to sent back the appropriate data elements in my put request?  I need to somehow remove departmentName and add the department id.

Here is my code:

**Component as used in form**

```
    <Controls.Dropdown
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        label='Department'
        name='departmentName'
        prompt='Select A Department...'
        url='/api/maintain/departments/'
        value={values.departmentName}
     />
```

**Dropdown**

```
   export default function Dropdown(props) {
      const { error = null, label, onChange, prompt, value, url, ...other } = props;
      const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
      const dropdownUrl = environment.originURL + environment.apiUrl + url; 

      React.useEffect(() => {
           const fetchData = async () => {
             const res = await axios.get(dropdownUrl);
             setOptions( res.data );
           };
           fetchData();
       }, [setOptions]); 

      return(
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant='outlined' >
            <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                defaultValue=''
                onChange={onChange}
                value={(value === undefined || value === null || options.length === 0) ? '' : value}
                {...other}
                {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
            >
                <MenuItem>{prompt}</MenuItem>
                {options.map((option, id) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        key={option.id}
                        value={option.name}
                    >
                        {option.name}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a request for the second API in your current code, so I can't suggest the exact code, but here's an idea how to combine the two responses from the two APIs:

```
const api_1_response = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "23456",
        "description": "New Location",
        "departmentName": "Tools"
    }
];

const api_2_response = [
    {
        "name": "Tools",
        "id": "1"
    }
];

const getFullDepartment = (department) => {
    const departmentDetails = api_1_response.find((item) => item.departmentName == department.name);
    
    if (departmentDetails) {
        return {
            "id": departmentDetails.id,
            "name": departmentDetails.name,
            "description": departmentDetails.description,
            "departmentOther": {
                "id": department.id
            }
        }
    } else {
        return department;
    }
}

const getFullDepartments = (departments) => {
    return departments.map((department) => {
        return getFullDepartment(department);
    });
}

console.log(getFullDepartments(api_2_response));
```

Also here are a couple of suggestions for your code:

1. You have the useEffect hook bound to the setOptions function, but it should be bound to a value, not a function. If you want it to run just once when the component mounts, you should leave the dependence array empty.
2. The destructuring should be in the function parameters of the component, not as another line of code, it will look cleaner :)